# Connect nginx with Xdebug

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug

I want to use Xdebug for my web project I do the configs and when I run this

```
php -S localhost:88 ./index.php
```

All things works fine and Xdebug works and stop in the breakpoints 
But When I want to load the page with nginx I got the problem 
The page load and my breakpoints dont stop the loading of the page 
I put my configs here 
**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9004,
            "stopOnEntry":true,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9004
        }
    ]
}
```

**nginx**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/azibom/Desktop/cyphy/cypht-master/site;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9004
```

And when I run this scrip

```
<?php

xdebug_info();
```

I got the 500 error in browser

Comment: When you request a PHP page (through your webserver/browser) with `<?php xdebug_info();` in it, what does it show? Does it show Xdebug at all? If not: You've changed the wrong `php.ini` file.

Comment: When I run `<?php xdebug_info();` I got the 500 error, so what is the problem with my `php.ini`?